# Как в qt Creatore сделать чтобы имена функций переписывались?

Tags: qt, юнит-тесты, qtcreator

Стокнулся с проблемой, создал юнит тест. Создал клас. В нем создал 6 функций. Но решил их переименновать. Но когда я  их переименовал  . При запуску юнит теста показываются старые имена файлов и то не все. У меня 6 а показываются только 3. Подскажите как сделать чтобы оно переделалось. Делаю qmake, rebuild, clean all не помагает

Вот:

```
 class EqualsTests : public QObject
 {
     Q_OBJECT

 public:
     EqualsTests();

 private Q_SLOTS:
    void equalTestTask();
    void equalTestTest();
    void equalTestCategory();
    void noEqualTestTask();
    void noEqualTestTest();
    void noEqualTestCategory();
```

};

Выводит:
    [image: что выводит]

Comment: попробуйте удалить вручную папку со сборкой и пересобрать

Comment: @BeardedBeaver удалил. Теперь кричит что нету .moc файлу(((  QT creator какойто глючный.